# load json in mg table gives a data is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, json

This script does not load any data.

```
<script lang="JavaScript">
    d3.json('file:///C:/Software/Data/dirk/development/D3_TestLab/data/StatusTabel.json', function (error,data) {

        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

        var table_data = data

        var table1 = MG.data_table({
            data: data, //table_data,
            //title: '',
            //description: 'A table has many of the same properties as any other data graphic.',
            show_tooltips: true
        })

            .target('#div1')

            .number({ accessor: 'BU', label: 'BU', width: 120, font_size: 14, layout: 'center' })
            .number({ accessor: 'Lines', label: 'Lines', width: 190, font_size: 14, layout: 'center' })
            .number({ accessor: 'Shift', label: 'Shift', width: 270, font_size: 14 })

            .display();
    })
</script>
```

I get the error:

> TypeError: a.data is undefined.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Code tags please also be more specific what are you trying to do what have you attempted?

Comment: Please formate your code.

Comment: [
{"BU": "Filtration","Lines": 400 ,"Errors": 1,"Shift": "Early"},
{"BU": "Filtration","Lines": 35 ,"Errors": 1,"Shift": "Late"}
] 
This is my json but still I don't get data loaded.

Comment: I try to load json data from a folder stored on my laptop into a metrics graphics data table.
The loading is done by D3.json and then placing the data is done by
MG.data_table function.

Only D3.json will not load the data.

Answer (score 0):

I try to load json data from a folder stored on my laptop into a metrics graphics data table.
The loading is done by D3.json and then placing the data is done by
MG.data_table function.

Only D3.json will not load the data.